# Trying to upload files, difficulties with arrays

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arraylist, multipart

I'm trying to upload files, but the Multipartfiles are not getting passed on properly.

Here is my controller where I'm trying to add some files. Only the @RequestParam gets returned, Arrays.asList(files) returns an empty array. I'll add the result of the print lines below.

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(path = "/profile/files", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Wrong file type", response = ErrorResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, message = "Not authorized", response = ErrorResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Internal Error", response = InternalErrorResponse.class)
    })
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Add files",
            tags = "Users"
    )
    public List<FileDto> addProfilePicture(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) {
        System.out.println("Controller: Files from params: " + files.toString());
        List<MultipartFile> filesToAdd = Arrays.asList(files);
        System.out.println("Controller: Files Array.asList: " + filesToAdd);
        List<File> savedFiles = userService.addFiles(filesToAdd);
        System.out.println("Controller: Files returned from addFiles(): " + savedFiles);
        return savedFiles.stream().map(FileDto::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

This is the service part:

```
public List<File> addFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {

        System.out.println("Service: Input files: " + files);

        List<File> savedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        for(MultipartFile file: files){
            File savedFile = fileService.save(file, FileService.LOCATION_DOCUMENT_FILE, S3Adapter.ACL_OWNER_ONLY);
            savedFiles.add(savedFile);
        }
        System.out.println("Service: Saved files: " + savedFiles);
        return savedFiles;
    }
```

This is what the print lines are producing for me when trying to upload images through Postman:

```
Controller: Files from params: [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;@794108b7
Controller: Files Array.asList: []
Service: Input files: []
Service: Saved files: []
Controller: Files returned from addFiles(): []
```

Comment: That means that postman doesn't submit any file, or that they are submitted under a param name different from "file".

Comment: But it shows that it's getting a MultipartFile from the params, the first print line?

Comment: No it is just showing that you have an Array, it maybe be empty

Comment: The first print line shows that `files` is a non null array. The other lines show that the array is empty.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @HeikoPiirme the toString function on an array is near useless, as it it not overwritten and returns an hashcode. Try to print the array.length instead of the toString if you want to see if the array is empty or contains something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like while you are uploading from POSTMAN, you are using `binary` option. This option only works if you are receiving as `HttpServletRequest / MultipartRequest`.

To receive the files as `@RequestParam("files")` you need to use `form-data` option and give the key as `files` and for value choose `file` from the dropdown, choose multiple files and submit the request. It will work fine.

[image: Screen Shot for your reference]